# Invisible reCaptcha doesn't trigger html5 form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I am not sure why my code doesn't trigger html5 form validation. I checked few posts here and implement their methods and none of them worked.

I am creating dynamic invisible reCaptcha forms and form validation is not working as it should be... I am not sure what is wrong and what did I do wrong...

Does someone knows the problem?

My code:

```
    $(function () {
    $("button.g-recaptcha").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var currentForm = $(this).closest("form");
        if(currentForm[0].checkValidity()) {
            grecaptcha.execute();
        }
        else{
            grecaptcha.reset();
        }
    });

});

var onloadCallback = function () {
    $("button.g-recaptcha").each(function () {
        var el = $(this);

        grecaptcha.render($(el).attr("id"), {
            "sitekey": "MY SITE KEY",
            "size": "invisible",
            "badge": "inline",
            "callback": function (token) {
                $(el).parent().find(".g-recaptcha-response").val(token);
                $(el).closest("form").submit();
            }
        }, true);
    });

};
```

JS code for form submitting:

```
$("#sendMessageButton").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if ($('#contact_topic').val() == '') {
            $('#contact_topic-button').popover({
                trigger: 'manual',
                html: 'true',
                placement: 'top',
                content: function () {
                    return messages.please_enter_the_required_fields_first;
                }
            }).popover('show');

            setTimeout(function () {
                $('.popover').fadeOut('slow', function () {
                });
            }, 2000);
            return;
        }
        if ($('#contact_topic_subcategory').val() == '') {
            $('#contact_topic_subcategory-button').popover({
                trigger: 'manual',
                html: 'true',
                placement: 'top',
                content: function () {
                    return messages.please_enter_the_required_fields_first;
                }
            }).popover('show');

            setTimeout(function () {
                $('.popover').fadeOut('slow', function () {
                });
            }, 2000);
            return;
        }

        var client = clientBrowser();

        $("#contact_os").val(client.os + ' ' + client.osVersion);
        $("#contact_client").val(client.client + ' ' + client.version);
        $("#contact_mobile").val(client.mobile);
        $("#contact_cookies").val(client.cookieEnabled);
        $("#contact_resolution").val(client.screenSize);
        $("#contact_window").val(client.windowSize);

        $("#contact-form").submit();
    });
```

twig/html:

```
<div class="signup-form contact-form">
    {{ form_start(form, { 'attr': {'id': 'contact-form'} }) }}
    {{ form_label(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
{% for flashMessage in app.session.flashbag.get('error') %}
    <div class="captcha-alert">
        <span class="icon-alert"> ! </span>
        {{ flashMessage }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
    <button id="sendMessageButton" class="btn btn--green">{{ "contact.send_message"|trans }}</button>
    <div class="validationHolder g-recaptcha" id="contactRecaptcha"></div>
    {{ form_end(form) }}

    {#<div class="send-message">#}
    {#<a href="" class="send-message-button" id="sendMessageButton">{{ "contact.send_message"|trans }}</a>#}
    {#</div>#}
</div>
```

This is console log of events:

```
CALLING SUBMIT
INSIDE ON SUBMIT
IS FORM VALID: false
```

Comment: Can you provide your HTML code ? Also have you debugged the code as I can't see any `console` in your code?

Comment: @swetanshkumar thank you for your comment. I updated my original question.

Comment: in your `button.g-recaptcha` click function you have used `closest("form")` but I am unable to find any `<form>` tag in your html code.

Comment: this line: {{ form_start(form, { 'attr': {'id': 'contact-form'} }) }} actually renders form.

Comment: I think that's issue which means while creating form dynamically , there is a catch. Can you try it by writing a static form as the static form is working for the function you wrote.